# Lambda expression where column is equal to list items

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a general result having different columns including **id** column. I also have a `List` which has a set of *id*'s. I want to get result where `List` item(id) matches the **Id** column value.

I tried doing this in a loop:

```
foreach(int Uid in idList)
{
    queryResults = queryResults.Where(security => security.id== Uid);
}
```

But this gives me single record in **queryResults** which is for the last **Uid** in List. What I want is, records for all **Uid**'s in List should be there in **queryResults**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to match the id of every item to the ids stored in your `idList`. This can be achieved by means of the `Where`-extension used on your `queryResult` in combination with the `Contains`-method used on the `idList`:

```
var idList = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4} // This is your list holding the ids
var result = queryResult.Where(security => idList.Contains(security.SecuritiesId));
```

This will check for every item of the `queryResult` whether its `SecuritiesId` is contained in the list containing the relevant ids.