# Lambda expression where id in list of ids

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have 2 lists

```
var listquestionold = db.tblExamQuetions.Where(p => p.QuetionExamId == oldexamid).ToList();
var listquestionnew = listquestionnew = db.tblExamQuetions.Where(p => p.QuetionExamId == examid ).ToList();
List<tblExamQuestionAnswers> listanswers = new List<tblExamQuestionAnswers>();
```

How can I get answers where `questionId` is in `listquestionold`:
`listanswers =db.tblanswers.where(p=> p.ExamQuestionId exists in listquestionold` ?

Comment: surely this must be a duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lambda expression - Where column is equal to list items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177967/lambda-expression-where-column-is-equal-to-list-items)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easy with [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the `List`:

```
var listquestionold = db.tblExamQuetions.Where(p => p.QuetionExamId == oldexamid).ToList();
var listanswers = db.tblanswers.Where(w => listquestionold.Contains(w.ExamQuestionId)).ToList();
```